# How can I remove paint splatters from sealed decorative concrete deck?

Tags: concrete, floor, deck, outdoor, paint-removal

I have a custom concrete pation & pool deck that is textured / painted to look like wood. It is also sealed. Recently I had the coping on my pool fixed and the guy did a great job but left quite a bit of paint stains & splatter around the pool.

What would be the best way to remove these? I am going to try to pressure wash this weekend but should I be using paint thinner? Can that be used on a sealed concrete deck without damaging it?

Comment: I would try in small steps > big steps. So start with something not very abrasive like a wash cloth.. Does it come off? If not, then up in course level a bit. Scrubbing like this should take off the paint without taking off the protective coating. BTW what was it sealed with? How long has the paint been sitting there?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I should have included what I have already done - I've tried scrubbing with a deck brush and it did not come off. I've contacted the company that recently did the deck to find out exactly what type of sealer they used (awaiting a response). The stains have been there about a week now.

Comment: It takes a *very* long time for paint to truly dry which is why I ask. A week is not very long so you may have some hope. I would try to get on your hands and knees with a scouring pad as well

Comment: Have you contacted the guy who left the paint splatters? Sounds like this would be his responsibility to fix.

Comment: @PhilippNagel - I sure have and am trying to get him to come out and take care of it. Funny how some contractors don't wait to return calls after they have been paid :) - Additionally I'm not sure I trust him to remove the paint stains without causing more damage

Comment: The other thing you need to find out is exactly what “paint” was used. If paint was used on the coping it’s likely urethane or epoxy, not your standard silicone based paint.

Comment: Great point @Tyson - I have the actual paint can at home so I will check. Thank you

Comment: I don't understand why people will spend good money having someone do work on their house then not expect the workers to clean up after themselves. The more often people are allowed to leave a mess like this behind, the more they expect to be able to do it in the future. You shouldn't have to clean up after them unless it was specifically written into your contract that you would.

Answer (score 0):

**This will only work if there's a handful of splatters**

Well technically if you've got unlimited time you could do this with an unlimited number of splatters.

What you do is get a icecube and a small chisel or something similar. You  hold the icecube on the paint splatter for a few seconds and then pry it up with your chisel or tap at it.

Since it's winter here it wouldn't work but if you're doing work around your pool I'm assuming you're in a southern climate. I've never tried it on very fine overspray but on splatters it works quite well and is very gentle on the surface underneath.

If it doesn't work on fine overspray and that's what you're trying to remove you could try Goof Off on a mildly damp cloth and with a light but rapid wiping motion see if you can get the paint off. *** be very careful as Goof Off is very aggressive, test in a small inconspicuous place first*** Goof Off evaporates extremely quickly and you would have to reapply a small amount frequently.

Comment: +1 for Goof Off. But before using the Goof Off, get the answer from the people that sealed your deck and see if they can give you a pint of it to touch up afterward if the Goof Off take too much off. He's right, it's "aggressive".

Comment: Why wouldn't this work in winter?  Wouldn't a freezing climate be ideal since the splatter is already frozen.  Assuming it's not covered by snow or ice, of course.

Answer (score 0):

At the paint store where I work (21 years), We have several products called, Liftoff and Krud Kutter. Both work equally well on paint spatters. Both are pretty safe as well.

I would like to know what the sealer is to make sure I am giving the proper recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

I recently splattered some latex paint on my composite (plastic) deck boards, and after trying a few of the obvious; Goof-off, etc.  discovered that plain isopropyl alcohol worked the best.  Spill a little on the spot, let it sit a minute then scrub with a paper towel.

Answer (score 0):

**Splatter by splatter**

[image: razor scraper]

Depicted: razor scraper.  I understand that you might be able to soften the paint with liquid soap.  If kids still do work for hire this seems like a kid speed job to me.  Shave off each splatter.