# How do I clean up paint on cement?

Tags: paint-removal

The painter used a sprayer to paint and it got on the cement floor around our house. What is the best way to remove the paint

You’ll see from the pictures that some of it is little droplets over large areas and some of it is concentrated paint in small areas.

[image: by door]
[image: by block wall]
[image: large area small droplets]

Comment: possible duplicate https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/159377/97780

Answer (score 2):

The actual best way may be to hold your final payment to your painter until he cleans it up!

I'm not trying to be a wise guy. If you paid someone to do this it shouldn't be left like that.

Answer (score -1):

laquer thinner and a wire brush

Comment: Please [improve your answer](https://diy.stackexchange.com/posts/165016/edit) by describing **how** to use the lacquer thinner and the wire brush. Thanks